# Can I use anonymous lambdas to hold on to static values?

Tags: c++, lambda, static, singleton, c++17

I have want to create an object that I want to keep out of scope, but set references to its fields. Is this approach any good?

```
A* a;
B* b;
[a, b]
{
   static Loader loader("some", "argument", "the constructor", "takes");
   a = loader.getA();
   b = loader.getB();
}();
```

Is the anonymous lambda destroyed with its owned values? Is there a better design pattern to achieve the same thing?

Okay it seems like this is a good approach. My question is still if the anonymous lambda is destroyed upon parsing or not (and with it the owned static variable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do static variables in lambda function objects work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391058/how-do-static-variables-in-lambda-function-objects-work)

Comment: @Shiro The question is more like, are anonymous lambdas temporary or not?

Comment: Why do you want to keep it out of scope? What's the problem?

Comment: @Barry I could very well keep my temporary loader it in scope, its just my obsession not to keep anything in scope that I don't actually want to access anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a lambda to do this.  `static` variables can be declared at block scope so you could refactor to

```
A* a;
B* b;
{
   static Loader loader("some", "argument", "the constructor", "takes");
   a = loader.getA();
   b = loader.getB();
}
// more code
```

and now `loader` can never be directly accessed again (it is out of scope) but you can store pointers/references to it or it's members (it's lifetime last until the end of he program).

---

Also, to answer you question about the lifetime of temporary lambdas, they are destroyed if you do not capture them.

```
[](){ /* some code */ }();
```

Will create an object, call its `operator()` and then destroy that temporary object.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Not sure if they a preferred or not but why create an object when all you need is a new scope?

Comment: Okay, wait, these braces are pointless, this does not move `loader` out of scope...

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Yes it does.  When you enter the `{` you enter a new scope.  Once you get to `//more code` that previous scope is now gone and you can't return to it.  If you had declared local variables in there they would be destroyed.

Comment: Ah, you are right, it indeed cannot be accessed. But the thing is, I want to return something from the lambda too, to assign a reference, thats why I want an anonymous lambda.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Then you probably need the lambda.

Comment: So the static variable would be stored on a free-d location, therefore the pointers would be dangling. This is the answer I wanted, thanks! I'll look for a workaround then :)

Comment: @AdamHunyadi No, the variable will still exist and the pointer will not dangle.  `static` variables live for the life of the program and are initialized they first the the initialization is reached.