# Can I really create a global variable with every declaration of a Type?

Tags: c++, lambda, static

So I wrote this code and was kind of surprised when it compiled (I am using gcc version 5.1.0):

```
struct Mine
{
    const int* ptr;
    Mine(const int x) 
      : ptr([=]()
         { 
           static const int n = x; 
           return &n; 
         }()
        ){}
};
Mine first = 12;
Mine second = 13;
```

The reason I am surprised is that each declaration of `Mine` creates a new "global" variable.

So here is the question:

Am I supposed to be allowed to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do static variables in lambda function objects work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391058/how-do-static-variables-in-lambda-function-objects-work)

Comment: Have you checked to see if `n` is actually a different value across the two objects? Because in regular functions, `static` variables are only initialized on the first call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one `n` and all `ptr`'s are equal.

So, no.

Comment: I figured it was going to be something like that

Comment: But why did it not give me an error or warning because all `n` is constant (so it does not make sense to try to give it multiple values)

Comment: @DarthRubik Why would it give you a warning?  The first time you invoke the lambda, it initializes `n`.  Every other time it just returns a pointer to it.