# lambda capture initializers warning for c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

There is c++ code like this:

```
auto func = [=, vec1=std::move(vec)]() {
                   printf("%x  %x  %x\n", p,vec1.data(), vec.data());
           };
```

when I compile it with `-std=c++11`, the compiler print `warning`

`lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14`,

But the code can run correctly, so should I need process this `warnning`.

Comment: Why not compile with `-std=c++14`?

Comment: If you want to support C++11, don't use C++14 features. If you want to use C++14, set your compiler to C++14 mode.

Comment: @songyuanyao These code need cross compile, so I need consider the plateform support c++14 or not, this is a history problem, so could not add c++14 directly

Comment: @sundq Then I don't think it's a good idea, i.e. compiling the code with c++11 mode with usage of the c++14 feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> so should I need process this warnning.

You should fix the code so that there is no warning.

There are two options: Compile in C++14 mode or later standard version where lambda capture initializers are allowed, or don't use `vec1=std::move(vec)` lambda initializer.

> These code need cross compile, so I need consider the plateform support c++14 or not, this is a history problem, so could not add c++14 directly

So choose the latter option. Don't use C++14 features if your target platform doesn't support it.

If you need to move into a capture, you can achieve it in C++11 using `std::bind`:

```
auto func = std::bind(
    [=](const decltype(vec)& vec1) {
       printf("%x  %x  %x\n", p,vec1.data(), vec.data());
   },
   std::move(vec)
);
```

---

P.S `%x` format specifier requires that the argument is `unsigned int` But the return type of `std::vector<T>::data` is not `unsigned int`, but `T*`, so the behaviour will be undefined. `%p` is for pointers.