# C++ How to use lambda expression to capture the previous iteration value?

Tags: c++

I'm using this simple example of creating a simple vector with its element in strictly increasing, random step manner. I have an implementation using function objects:

```
struct IncrementGenerator
{
    int m;
    IncrementGenerator() : m(0) {}
    int operator()()
    {
        m += 1 + (rand() % 5);     //random Increment between [1,5]
        return m;
    }
};

vector<int> myVector(10);
generate(myVector.begin()+1, myVector.end(), IncrementGenerator());

//example of the output: 0, 4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 17, 20, 25,
```

I've just learnt lambda expression today and would like to do the same implementation in much short code. I'm not sure if I can capture the previous iteration in the lambda expression and add on a random number onto it:

```
// my idea is such, but not really sure what to write in the expression so i put some question mark.
generate(myVector.begin()+1, myVector.end(),[?]()->int{return ? + (1 + (rand()%5)) });
```

Comment: Read more some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).  Read a good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/). You might want to use some [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: A simple `int m = 0;` followed by `[&m]` and `return m += ...` should work. If you want the value of `m` to be persistent across multiple calls to the lambda, capture it by reference.

Comment: Unrelated but I would rather use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution instead of rand. This is a really nice talk which explains why https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DPkyvkMkk8.

Comment: Although the asked question is different, the answers apply: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8391058/315052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda equivalent to the class above is this:

```
auto increment_generator = [m = 0]() mutable
{
    m += 1 + (rand() % 5);     //random Increment between [1,5]
    return m;
};
```

Note the `mutable` modifier which indicates that the captured `m` is not constant. By default, variables captured by lambdas are `const`.