# Minimizing the scope of objects for a lambda expression

Tags: c++, optimization

I was wondering if there is some tool in C++ that I don't know yet that can minimize the scope of my objects and functions in the following simple example where I fill a vector with random dice rolls:

```
std::vector<int> dice_samples(10);
std::mt19937_64 m_gen;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);

std::generate(dice_sample.begin(), dice_sample.end(), [&](){
    return dist(m_gen);
    });
```

Ideally, I want both the Generator and Distribution to be scoped within the generate call. I could move their construction into the lambda expression but something like this would seem extremely inefficient as I would be constructing a Generator and Distribution on each call:

```
std::vector<int> dice_samples(10);

std::generate(dice_sample.begin(), dice_sample.end(), [](){
    std::mt19937_64 m_gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);
    return dist(m_gen);
    });
```

In other words is there a way to scope the construction and destruction of a object once within a function call or lambda expression? Or is this not yet possible in the latest version of C++?

Comment: You know, I've never tried defining a `static` variable inside a lambda. I think I have something new to look up. [How do static variables in lambda function objects work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391058/how-do-static-variables-in-lambda-function-objects-work) seems to answer that. Looks like you can use `static`.

Comment: @user4581301 I did, but mostly as some counters, instead of capturing external counter. might be confusing with generic lambdas.. they are considered templates

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie You're probably right. A comment in above-link warns of that. Shouldn't be a problem for a trivial case like this, though.

Comment: @user4571391 interesting I also never thought about using static in a lambda before. I wonder if its even worth it given the performance penalty (if there is any) of using static in this case.

Comment: Note that the above musings are probably useless to the asker. Access is nicely scoped, but the lifetime of the RNG variables is potentially gross. Suckers will be with the program until the end of days.

Comment: @SamXu I'm not sure what the overhead is. There must be some cost. `static` initialization is thread safe so there must be some cost. And it looks like J. Schultke just covered this in their answer. Going to poke at this a bit more.

Comment: I have a question though, if problem only organizational, why not organize those objects, functor, etc. into scope of a single class? Or, if  language standard allows, use capture with initialization, that'd be an equivalent

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I came over this question while I was writing a unit-test for a algorithm. Creating a class or function to scope this one-time process seemed a bit excessive for the task at hand. I am currently trying to improve my modern c++ so I was pondering over what the most idiomatic and expressive way of writing is. I think the capture + initialization + mutable was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a capture with an initializer (but the lambda then has to be `mutable`, because the generator can't be const):

```cpp
std::vector<int> dice_samples(10);

std::generate(dice_samples.begin(), dice_samples.end(), [m_gen=std::mt19937_64{}, dist=std::uniform_int_distribution<int>{}]() mutable {
    return dist(m_gen);
});
```

Or you can just create another scope:

```cpp
std::vector<int> dice_samples(10);

{
    std::mt19937_64 m_gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);

    std::generate(dice_sample.begin(), dice_sample.end(), [&](){
        return dist(m_gen);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple possible solutions. First of all, you could put variables and the call to `std::generate` in a scope:

```cpp
std::vector<int> dice_samples(10);
{
    std::mt19937_64 m_gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);
    std::generate(dice_sample.begin(), dice_sample.end(), [&m_gen, &dist](){
        return dist(m_gen);
    });
}
```

You could also use a `static` variable inside the lambda:

```cpp
std::vector<int> dice_samples(10);
std::generate(dice_sample.begin(), dice_sample.end(), [&m_gen, &dist](){
    static std::mt19937_64 m_gen;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 6);
    return dist(m_gen);
});
```

Note that `static` mutable variables come with some amount of overhead, because the compiler needs to initialize them the first time the function is called in a thread-safe manner:

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static or `thread_local` (since C++11) have static or thread (since C++11) storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

(see [static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables))

In your case this should be negligible though.
Also keep in mind that mutating `static` variables isn't thread safe. You mutate the PRNG when using it.

Comment: Since a lambda is a compiler-generated type, and that type is instantiated when the lambda is declared, wouldn't making the variables be `static` inside the lambda cause them to live for the lifetime of the program once the lambda is invoked? If so, it would seem better to use a local scope instead so that new variables are created and destroyed each time a new `generate()` call is needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it would be more efficient for all `static` local variables to be initialized when the program starts, but it would violate the standard. See the edit. In practice, maybe the compiler will detect that a PRNG can be initialized at compile time. That depends on its implementation though.