# Why is a C++ lambda life cycle bound to the smallest block scope?

Tags: c++, lambda, static

In the following example program, I would expect the counter to reset at the beginning of each cycle:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void run_lambda(std::function<void()> fun){ fun(); fun(); }
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i){
        run_lambda([i](){
            static int testVal = 0;
            std::cout << "value[" << i << "]:" << testVal << std::endl;
            ++testVal;
        });
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead the output is:

```
value[0]:0
value[0]:1
value[1]:2
value[1]:3
value[2]:4
value[2]:5
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391983/1467600):

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

In my understanding this means, that the lambda object life cycle is bound to the loops block scope, thus the static variable is not resetting at the start of the loop.

Is there a specific reason for this? Intuitively one would think that a lambda expression is essentially a temporary object, and as such in this example it would cease to exist after the statement.

Comment: Scoping is irrelevant. This is no different than an ordinary function with a `static` variable. If your closure was this ordinary function, instead, when would you expect this `static` variable to become 0 again, and why?

Comment: As I wrote in the question I expected the variable to reset at the beginning of the cycle, as  I believed the lambda object of a temporary, and expected that with each call of `run_lambda` essentially a new object is generated

Comment: What does a lambda object have to do with a class method or a function? The lambda object is just an instance of an anonymous class, and the lambda itself is an ordinary method, or function in that class. If the lambda was an ordinary function or a method, when, exactly, would you expect the `static` variable to reset itself to 0, and why? If you create an instance of a class, with a static method that looks like this, call it, destroy that class instance, and create another instance of that class, and call the same method, would you expect the `static` variable to reset itself to 0, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is basically equivalent to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct lambda
{
  lambda(int i): i(i) {}
  int i;
  void operator()()
  {
    static int testVal = 0;
    std::cout << "value[" << i << "]:" << testVal << std::endl;
    ++testVal;
  }
};

void run_lambda(std::function<void()> fun){ fun(); fun(); }
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i){
        lambda l{i};
        run_lambda(l);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whilst each iteration of the loop does indeed create a new lambda object each object is an instance of the same class and therefore shares the same static variables.

The statement you're quoting is saying that the type is declared inside the scope where the lambda is declared. It isn't saying that each time the code enters that scope a new type is created (c++ doesn't have dynamic types like that).